# Attach onclick to HTML received from API

Tags: angular, onclick, ionic3, dynamic-content

I have a page that receives it's HTML-Contents from an API.

In that code there are DIVs with the class "openMap".
When the user clicks on those DIVs I want a function to be executed (alert('yes') in the example below).

I have tried the following but while the

```
console.log(elementsWithClass[i]);
```

does output the HTML of each element, I can not add a click-event.

How can this be achieved?
Current code:

```
this.http.get(httpGetUrl)
        .subscribe(data => {
            let returnedHtml = data['_body'];
            if(returnedHtml != ''){
                this.notdienstHtml = returnedHtml;
                this.zone.run(() => {
                    let elementsWithClass = document.getElementsByClassName("openMap");
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        console.log(elementsWithClass.length);
                        for (let i=0; i < elementsWithClass.length; i++) {
                            console.log(elementsWithClass[i]); //correctly outputs HTML-content of each DIV it iterates over
                            elementsWithClass[i].onclick = function(){
                                //not run when DIV is clicked
                                alert('yes');
                            }
                        };
                    }, 300);
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with.
Important thing is, if the content is dynamic, update it via element.innerHtml in the ts-file not with [innerHtml] in the html-file.

in the HTML

```
<div #mainHtml id="mainHtml"></div>
```

before the constructor:

```
@ViewChild('mainHtml') mainHtml: ElementRef;
```

function:

```
this.http.get(httpGetUrl)
        .subscribe(data => {
            let returnedHtml = data['_body'];
            if(returnedHtml != ''){
                let nativEl = this.mainHtml.nativeElement;
                nativEl.innerHTML = returnedHtml; //update the HTML
                let elements = nativEl.querySelectorAll('.openMap'); //openMap is the css selector
                for(let element of elements){
                    element.addEventListener('click', this.openMap.bind(this)); //openMap is the function name
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to bind the event from the component where the response will rendered.

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('my-element')
                                .addEventListener('click', this.onClick.bind(this));
}

onClick(event) {
  console.log(event);
}
```